# How might we understand the phrase "on goal"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, semantics

The sentence is,

> He [the goalie] is pretty much incapable of thwarting even the most
> fainthearted attempts **on goal**.

- Source - *[Own Goal](https://harpers.org/archive/2010/06/own-goal/)*

The meaning seems clear: the goalie is failing to prevent goals.

But why the phrase "on goal"? Is this a prepositional phrase, or a phrasal preposition? What analogues are there to this usage? How does the *on* come to mean something like "to make a goal"?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141069/discussion-on-question-by-pound-hash-how-might-we-understand-the-phrase-on-goal).

Comment: "on goal" is modifying "attempts". An attempt on goal is an attempt to score a goal.